# "dep init -v", it do not generate Gopkg.toml and Gopkg.lock, why?

Tags: go, vendor

When I run `dep init`, it takes long time, and it does not generate `Gopkg.toml` and `Gopkg.lock`. Why aren't these files getting generated?

The code is [here](https://github.com/dean-su/micro-youtube-drizzler/tree/master/srv/download)

```
zhiwei@myVM:~/go/bin$ ll
total 29164
drwxr-xr-x 2 zhiwei zhiwei     4096 Mar  1 08:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 zhiwei zhiwei     4096 Feb 28 21:22 ../
-rwxrwxr-x 1 zhiwei zhiwei 13413097 Mar  1 08:52 dep*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zhiwei zhiwei 16437361 Feb 26 21:35 micro*
zhiwei@myVM:~/go/bin$ cd ../src/github.com/micro-youtube-
drizzler/srv/download/
zhiwei@myVM:~/go/src/github.com/micro-youtube-drizzler/srv/download$ l
bak/  Dockerfile*  main.go*  proto/  README.md*
zhiwei@myVM:~/go/src/github.com/micro-youtube-drizzler/srv/download$ dep init -v
Getting direct dependencies...
Checked 3 directories for packages.
Found 7 direct dependencies.
```

Comment: Are you sure you have proper 'GOPATH'?
Does it produce any errors?

Comment: That is very strange ! I finished the coding, then runned "dep init" and that hold always. But I cleaned the  folder, then runned "dep init", and generated the  Gopkg.toml and Gopkg.lock.